# Intro to popular rock music

Tags: rock

I was raised in a home whose music appreciation mostly centered around church music. I don't mean Christian rock, gospel, or anything like that—more like large chamber choir music. As a teenager I learned to love jazz, alternative rock, and pop music. Now I am learning the guitar, and would love to become well-acquainted with rock and roll. However, I know very little about real rock. I'm wondering if there are certain songs I can listen to to become more familiar with rock that would give me a good introduction into this genre. I've heard/heard of some rock songs that I think are probably considered "classics", but, as a total rock-noob, my exposure has been limited only to what I've heard in movie soundtracks and pop culture. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Kenny. Are you OK if these songs deal with some explicit topics such as insults, drugs, love (which are very common in rock music)?

Answer (score 2):

Rock has such a long and diverse history, it's difficult to give a single list, since early rock is utterly different than contemporary rock.  The closest you can probably come to a canonical list is something like this one from *Rolling Stone* magazine, the most famous and influential rock-oriented magazine:  http://www.chicagotribune.com/entertainment/sns-rolling-stone-top-songs-pictures-photogallery.html

If I was going to give my own, highly-subjective list --of *iconic* rock songs, not necessarily personal favorites -- it would probably include:

**PRE-ROCK**
"Strange Things Happening Every Day" - Sister Rosetta Tharpe
"Tutti Frutti" - Little Richard
"Blueberry Hill" - Fats Domino
**EARLY**
"Johnny B Goode" - Chuck Berry
"Hound Dog" - Elvis Presley
"Great Balls of Fire" - Jerry Lee Lewis
**CLASSIC**
"Be My Baby" - Ronettes
"Like a Rolling Stone" - Bob Dylan (named #1 by *Rolling Stone*)
"Satisfaction" - Rolling Stones
"Purple Haze" - Jimi Hendrix
**PROGRESSIVE**
"Time Has Come" - Chambers Brothers
"Stairway to Heaven" - Led Zepplin
"Comfortably Numb" - Pink Floyd
"Bohemian Rhapsody" - Queen
**NEW ORLEANS**
"Tipitina" - Professor Longhair
**METAL**
"Enter Sandman" - Metallica
"Ironman" - Black Sabbath
**80s ROCK REVIVAL**
"I Love Rock and Roll" - Joan Jett
"Walk This Way" - Aerosmith / Run DMC
"Rock and Roll, Hootchie Koo" - Rick Derringer
"What's Love Got to Do With It?" - Tina Turner
"Born in the USA" - Bruce Springsteen
"Old Time Rock n Roll" - Bob Seger
"Purple Rain" - Prince
"One" - U2  (really 90s, but pre-grunge)
**90s GRUNGE & ALTERNATIVE**
"Smells Like Teen Spirit" - Nirvana
"Say it Ain't So" - Weezer
"Creep" - Radiohead
**2000s**
"Hey Ya!" - Outkast
"Seven Nation Army" - White Stripes
"Tribute" - Tenacious D
**Contemporary**
"Tighten Up" - The Black Keys
"Sail" - AWOLNation
"Radioactive" - Imagine Dragons

I've left off some of my own favorite rock songs and groups --such as the immortal Beatles --because, while they were rock musicians, and their songs are iconic, their best songs are not iconic *as* rock, but as their own individual thing.  I've also included some not-so-favorites because they *are* iconic as rock.

At any rate, although I'm sure there could be a ton of arguments over any particular song on this list, together, they'll give you a good, roughly chronological sense of the shape of rock over the years from the 50s to the early 2000s.

Immortalized as a playlist here for your convenience and listening pleasure: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LzqGq6jiorg&list=PLuH0DI0d4JB_ymm8IFfiR2Mhuep3rHR-t

Comment: Be careful some of this songs might have some explicit topics so we should warn OP.

Comment: @Bebs Do you think so?  I guess Hey Ya is a tiny bit risque, and "Enter Sandman" has some dark imagery, but I'm really not seeing a need for a warning label here.  It also doesn't sound like OP is still a child or a teenager.  I guess some of these songs were controversial when they first came out, but by modern standards...

Comment: @Bebs I guess I'm used to the radio edit!  Hopefully he isn't shocked by reading your comment :)  Also... sex, drugs and rock and roll: this really isn't the genre for you if you're easily offended...

Comment: You're right, I was going to say that.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a wiki question, but My Bloody Valentine "Loveless," The Pixies, and Sonic Youth "Daydream Nation" are probably completely obscure by "pop culture exposure" standards, but were amazingly influential to other bands.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7VhNjZXALU